Fuselage contribution to pitching moment for a canard design
I am trying to calculate the pitching moment of a fuselage. I am currently looking into the Munk-Multhopp method. The equation for it are given as:

where,

The next step includes dividing the fuselage into sections and calculating the summation term.
My questions are:

For a design with a fore and aft wing, what is the definition of 'S'? Is it the total wing planform area (fore + aft wing) or just the main wing planform area?

Is there another way to estimate the pitching moment contribution due to the fuselage?



Chapter 4.2.2 of the USAF STABILITY AND CONTROL DATCOM should help.
